# Area of intersection between two polygons: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, buffer, intersection

I am trying to compute the area of the intersection of two polygons as follows:

```
inter = geomap_ilot.sjoin(df_final_quartiers_arrond)

def f(frame):
    """A function to calculate overlap percentage""" 
       
    interpct = 100*frame.g1.intersection(frame.g2).area/frame.g1.area
  
    return area

inter['pct'] = inter.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I get an error as follows:

```
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at -7.7398160754704346 33.535735521746396
```

I checked the validity of polygons `g1` and `g2` and they are all `1` which means they are valid. Then, I tried the `buffer(0)` function but I am still getting the same error:

```
100*frame.g1.intersection(frame.g2.buffer(0)).area
```

Any other suggestion on how I can fix the problem?

Comment: what is the aim of adding a `grid_size`? what is the difference with `buffer`?  Both geometries/CRS are 4326 so the areas are indeed in degrees. However, since this is a ratio of areas, the units drop. The result will be the same regardless of the units used I think

Comment: I tried the `grid_size` approach but got this error `TypeError: BaseGeometry.intersection() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grid_size'`

Comment: I tried this adjustment: `frame['g1']=frame['g1'].buffer(0.00001)
    frame['g2']=frame['g2'].buffer(0.00001)
    interpct = 100*frame.g1.intersection(frame.g2).area/frame.g1.area`   the function worked fine. It is strange no?

Comment: Buffering sometimes work. In QGIS or PostGIS I usually try repairing the geometries, snap them to grid, and/or buffering. Most times it solves the problem